# How to clone a single file using SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Lets say I have two projects in sync with online repos:

- Project - A consisting of files A1, A2, A3  (repo-A)
- Project - B consisting of files B1, B2, B3 (repo-B)

Now, if I need A2 in Project-B, how do I clone using SourceTree just the file A2 from repo-A into Project-B?

Comment: Can you not just copy it from the filesystem. Since the online repos are different would you want to clone is my question.

Comment: @82Tuskers Right now I am copying it from the filesystem. I thought of cloning because I want to keep track of A2. i.e. If someone makes any changes to A2 (via Project-A) and pushes to repo-A, I should be able to pull those changes while working on Project-B.

Comment: @82Tuskers may be clone is the wrong terminology. I just want to pull the changes on A2 to Project-B and not be able to push changes from project-B to A2 (repo-A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a solution could be to use git submodules. Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Submodules help you nest another repo with an existing repo. The only (possible) downside that I see is that, it will create a folder which contains the sub-project (in your case folder A within folder B). I think this shouldn't be a problem.

STEPS:

1. (Please ensure your git project directory is clean since we use `git
   reset HEAD` below)
2. cd path/to/main-project
3. git submodule add http://url-to-subproject
4. touch .gitignore
5. Add your submodule project folder name into the file. Ex., If your submodule folder is 'a' then add `a/*`.
6. git reset HEAD
7. You should still see .gitmodules and .gitignore when you run `git diff`.
8. Commit these files.

USAGE: 
If you want to update your subproject just `cd` into it and then run `git fetch` and `git pull` (normal operations to pull from remote) in your subproject folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @82Tuckers Thank you. I think nesting git is the only way forward for now.

Comment: @82Tuckers Since there are no simple solutions, I am now thinking that pulling a single file into another project may not be popular among developers?

Comment: @user2979010 What do you mean with "pulling a single file into another project"? I don't want the overhead of a whole subproject of countless files if I need just 1 of them. I have no problem with just copying it to another project - as long as there are no extremely important updates to be expected, which could somehow be forgotten...